# getting object value on php , no idea why error

Tags: php, html

```
Array[1]
0: Object
id: "1"name: "Jonny"
number: "27"
__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]
```

this is how my object look , i wanted to get the inner object one by one , but i tried and i have no idea why i have problem of it.

i am sending it by ajax and to a php, here is how i get from php

```
<?php
    $playBox = $_POST['play_data'];
    foreach($playBox as $obj){
        echo json_encode($obj);
    }
?>
```

my error

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
        <tr>
            <th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\objecttest\directory\class-mail.php on line <i>5</i></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th>
            <th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th>
            <th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th>
            <th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0005</td>
            <td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>135368</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td>
            <td title='C:\wamp\www\objecttest\directory\class-mail.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\class-mail.php<b>:</b>0</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</font>
```

what did i miss ? how i get the object value ?

Comment: shouldn't it be json_decode

Comment: ahh i think json_encode is right , i got the value return if normal variable

Comment: share your ajax code also ?

Answer (score 0):

Your  $playBox  is null  be  sure that you have and entry named `play_data`  in you post

```
 $playBox = $_POST['play_data'];
```

eventually try var_dump($_POST) for check

Answer (score 0):

Your object is inside of `array[0]`. So try:

```php
<?php
    $playBox = $_POST['play_data'];
    if($playBox) {
        foreach($playBox[0] as $obj) {
            echo json_encode($obj);
        }
    } else {
        echo "No Record Found";
    }
?>
```